# Compiler settings to code in C with Proteus

Tags: pic, c, microchip, proteus

I have made a circuit for a game called catch the light on Proteus. I have a C code for that. But I don't know how to set compilers and all that. I tried to add source code but due to some compiler settings, my circuit is not working as I want. I have downloaded Digital Mars C but have no idea what to do next. My code is fine, I only need help in settings.

Find my 
[circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBkfA.png) there. Also, I have coded [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94ZwL.png) way (screenshot added just to show the settings not the code.). And also see my [config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf5hl.png) settings. Here is my code:

```
#pragma config FOSC = XT    //Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF   //Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OF   //Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF  //Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF    //Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit 
#pragma config CPD = OFF    //Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit 
                            // (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF    //Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits 
                           //(Write protection off; all program memory may 
                           //be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF    //Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit 
(Code protection off)

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#include <xc.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int rand_num;  
int old_rand_num;
int score;
int score_tens;
int score_ones;
int shifter;
int delay;

//a function that varies the delay. Because passing variables to __delay_ms() doesnt work
void someDelay(){
switch(delay){
    case 500:
        __delay_ms(500);
        break;
    case 200:
        __delay_ms(200);
        break;
    case 100:
        __delay_ms(100);
        break;
    case 50:
        __delay_ms(50);
        break;
}
return;
}
void main(void) {

T1CON = 0b00000001;             //turn on TMR1
INTCON = 0b10101000;            //use global, TMR0 and RB change interrupts
OPTION_REG = 0b00000100;        //use 1:32 prescale for TMR0
TRISB = 0xF0;                   //inputs on RB4 to RB7, outputs for RB0 to RB3
TRISC = 0;                      //all PORTC are outputs
TRISD = 0;                      //all PORTD are outputs

delay = 500;                    //default delay

loop:
while(1){
    srand(TMR1);                //use TMR1 value as seed for random
    rand_num = rand() % 9;      //generate random numbers from 0 to 9
    //filter out consecutive numbers, 0 and those that has at least two bits high (011 = 3, 101 = 5, 110 = 6, 111 = 7)
    if(rand_num == old_rand_num || rand_num == 0 || rand_num == 3 || rand_num == 5 || rand_num == 6 || rand_num == 7){ 
        goto loop;
    }
    PORTD = rand_num;           
    old_rand_num = rand_num;    //
    someDelay();                //a function that varies the delay. Because passing variables to __delay_ms() doesn't work 
}

return;
}

void interrupt isr(void){
if(TMR0IF){
     //switch digits for every interrupt. Read about POV for better 
understanding
        shifter++;        
        switch(shifter){
            case 1:
                PORTB = 0b11111110;
                PORTC = score_ones;
                break;
            case 2:
                PORTB = 0b11111101;
                PORTC = score_tens;
                break;
            case 6:
                shifter = 0;
                break;
        }
        TMR0IF = 0;     //manual clearing of interrupt flag
}
if(RBIF){
    int dummy = PORTB;          //read PORTB to clear mismatch condition
    int masked = (PORTB & 0xF0) >> 4;   //acquire pressed buttons
    if(~masked == (PORTD + 0xFFF0)){
        score++;
        score_tens = score/10;
        score_ones = score - score_tens*10;
        //adjust speed according to score
        if(score <= 5){ 
            delay = 500;
        }else if(score > 5 && score <= 10){
            delay = 200;
        }else if(score > 10 && score <= 20){
            delay = 100;
        }else if(score > 20 && score <= 30){
            delay = 50;
        }else if(score > 99){
            score = 99;
        }else{
            delay = 500;
        }
    }
    RBIF = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: What processor is this for? You will need the XC compiler, probably XC8, but it depends on the target.

Comment: @RonBeyer Can you tell me step by step? I'm new to Proteus and compiler things.

Comment: You still haven't identified what processor this is for... I'm not all that familiar with Proteus, but you should download the correct tools, namely MPLAB X, you can then start a new project for your processor, paste your code in, and compile it. Out the other end should be a .bin or .elf file that Proteus should be able to load.

Comment: Have you seen the config named screenshot? It asks to visit the website. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Doesn't Proteus have a supporting forum to ask all these questions?